# JavaFX - Manage Objects between Tabs

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, fxml

I have a Controller, let's call it GeneralController, that creates a TabPane as well as two new tabs. The new tabs all get their own controller, "Tab1Controller" and "Tab2Controller".
Within the GeneralController, I create an Object "MyObject". This Object contains some data, that can be modified within Tab1Controller and Tab2Controller.
So far, so good.

"Tab1Controller" and "Tab2Controller" both have a initController function, which gets "MyObject" as a parameter. This way, I can initalize both Controllers with "MyObject".

GeneralController:

```
// Similar function for Tab2Controller
private void createTab1(ObjectProperty<MyObject> myObject) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("path/to/tab1.fxml"));

        Tab tab1 = (Tab) loader.load();

        Tab1Controller tab1Controller = loader.getController();
        tab1Controller.initController(myObject)

        generalTabs.getTabs().add(tab1);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Tab1Controller/Tab2Controller:

```
public void initController(ObjectProperty<MyObject> myObject) {
    this.myObject = myObject;
}
```

Here comes my question:
How do I ensure in the best way, that I keep my Labels, Controls, Nodes, Charts, whatever, up-to-date within Tab1Controller and Tab2Controller?

Is it reasonable to create a setOnSelectionChanged-Listener in Tab1Controller and Tab2Controller, and update all possible data-changes?

Comment: I think it is enough to invoke initController() again on tab change listener. In change listener: newTab.initController(currentMyObject);

Comment: Of course, that is a pretty good idea, thanks!
A few minutes after I've created this question, I just realized something: myObject is always up-to-date when switching through tabs. My concern is with keeping all my Controls, Labels, Charts, etc. up to date.
I guess, that I could create own Variables in TabController, and keep them up-to-date with bindings from myObject. Within the changeListener I then would have to update my Controls, Labels, etc.
Does this make sense?

Comment: How are you initting these controls on first view of tab after calling initController(myObject)?

Comment: The controls within TabController are initially created with the FXMLLoader in GeneralController (see example in the initial post). In TabController I merely access these controls with "@FXML private Label myControl". In the setOnSelectionChanged-Listener I would then have to update all these controls with the modified myObject, when the tab is selected. I don't know if this is a common approach to this problem, or if I am just making it complicated.

Comment: I actually meant, are you setting as myConrtol.setText(myObject.getSomeValue()); in some method? If yes you can reinvoke that method with currunt updated myObject instance.

Comment: Ah, I see. Very good Idea, I guess that's the most convenient way to do this.

Comment: Side note: I don't think it's a good idea to share  property objects (`public void initController(ObjectProperty<MyObject> myObject)`). Either share the content (`public void initController(MyObject myObject)`) or bind the properties. A property belongs to one bean class ("it's a property of the bean").

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'm still new to all that JavaFX stuff, and I'm still learning all the used programming patterns.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be using the [`observer pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
If you need a good example, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897878/using-observer-pattern-to-move-labels-javafx)